# Tapestry 5, loading css from filesystem

Tags: css, web-applications, loading, tapestry

We are creating a Tapestry 5 webapp with an external designer creating and maintaining the css-files of the application.

We would like him to be able to make changes to the css-files without the need to change the webapp, prefarably in the configurable path in the filesystem.

So what would the best way to do this with Tapestry 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a JIRA for the ability to use a [filesystem asset](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-423). Someone has posted patches that should let you do it but it hasn't made it into a release yet. If you do that, you could use `@IncludeStyleSheet(value={"file:path_to_css_file"})` in your layout template.

An alternate way would be to stream it using a method like [this one.](http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowToStreamAnExistingBinaryFile) The last paragraph suggests that you can include a streamed response in your template so in this case you could do `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${externalStylesheet}"/>`. Then create a streamed response that reads the stylesheet from a known path on the server. Or you could store it in a blob in the database and stream from there - that way you could also create a page to let the designer upload new versions.